# How to add JCE to JRE bundle in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j, jce

I need to create installer using [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) with the bundled JRE inside. When user installs it he gets app.exe without need to install JRE/JDK. But there is [bouncy castle lib](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) which requires [JCE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html). After installation I can manually add JCE to jre bundle, but I need installer does it by itself.

How to create JRE/JDK bundle with JCE using install4j? Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the version you're bundling (Java 8.152) you might be able to get by with just calling `Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");` in your main class code.
And if you can use a more recent version, JCE may be enabled by default.

Source: The answers and comments at [Why are the JCE Unlimited Strength not included by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159690/why-are-the-jce-unlimited-strength-not-included-by-default)