# 404 when trying to download JCE 8 policy from Oracle

Tags: java, java-8, cryptography, jce

I'm needing to download the JCE 8 policy that's normally available on Oracles website, but the last 2 days it seems to be giving me a 404 after accepting their T&C's
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html

Anyone have an alternative download source? Or any advice on how to ask Oracle what the deal is.

Comment: If you are using build 151 or later you no longer need this. Unlimited cryptography [is the default for those builds](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u161-relnotes.html#JDK-8170157). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371568/238704

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jceunlimitedstrghpolicyfilereadme-2864390.html) from oracle.com,

> Due to import control restrictions of some countries, the version of
> the JCE policy files that are bundled in the Java Runtime Environment,
> or JRE(TM), 8 environment allow "strong" but limited cryptography to
> be used.

Please check your JRE folder once.

Comment: I used to be able to download it 3 days ago.. so i don't think it's a country problem (Aus)

Answer (score 0):

(When I tried to download the file to see what happens, after accepting the T&C's I was sent to a page that said that I would need to login using my Oracle account.  I assume that you did that ...)

If there was an alternative download source, that would most likely be a violation of US export law.

There are a few possibilities as to what is going on:

- The Oracle download mechanisms for that link is broken.
- Something at your end is blocking the download.  (A local proxy or firewall for example?)
- The Oracle server thinks that you are downloading from a country that is on the cryptography export blacklist.
- You actually are downloading from a country that is on the cryptography export blacklist.
- Possibly something else ... that I am not in a position to know anything about.

I suggest that you contact Oracle and get them to help you with your problem.